# Full software timer : derivate time?

Tags: timer, hardware

I have been asked a question but I am not sure if I answered it correctly.

**"Is it possible to rely only on software timer?"**

My answer was **"yes, in theory"**.

**But** then I added:

> "Just relying on hardware timer at the kernel loading (rtc) and then
>   software only is a **mess** to manage since we must be able to know
>   how many cpu cycles each instruction took + eventual cache miss +
>   branching cost + memory speed and put a counter after each one or
>   group (good luck with out-of-order cpu).
>
> And do the calculation to derivate the current cpu cycle. That is
>   insane.
>
> **Not talking about the overall performance drop**.
>
> The best we could have is a brittle approximation of the time which
>   become **more wrong over time**. Even *possibly* on short laps."

But even if it seems logical to me, did *my* thinking go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't clear.  What are you trying to time?  What is "software hardware"?

Comment: You probably mean "software timer", not "software hardware"

Comment: Definitely, what a stupid typo! sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On current processors and hardware (e.g. Intel or AMD or ARM in laptops or desktops or tablets) with common operating systems (Linux, Windows, FreeBSD, MacOSX, Android, iOS, ...) processes are [scheduled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29) at random times. So cache behavior is non deterministic. Hence, instruction timing is non reproducible. You *need* some hardware time measurement.

A typical desktop or laptop gets hundreds, or thousands, of [interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) every second, most of them time related. Try running `cat /proc/interrupts` on a Linux machine twice, with a few seconds between the runs.

I guess that even with a single-tasked MS-DOS like operating system, you'll still get random behavior (e.g. induced by ACPI, or [SMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode)). On some laptops, the processor frequency can be throttled by its temperature, which depends upon the CPU load and the external temperature...

In practice you really want to use some timer provided by the operating system. For Linux, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

So **you practically *cannot* rely on a *purely software* timer**. However, the processor has internal timers.... Even in principle, you cannot avoid timers on current processors ....

You might be able, if you can put your hardware in a very controlled environment (thermostatically) to run a very limited software (an OS-like free standing thing) sitting entirely in the processor cache and perhaps then get some determinism, but in practice current laptop or desktop (or tablet) **hardware is *non-deterministic* and you cannot predict the time needed for a given small machine routine**.

Timers are extremely useful in interesting (non-trivial) software, see e.g. J.Pitrat [CAIA, a sleeping beauty](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/05/caia-a-sleeping-beauty/) blog entry for an interesting point. Also look at the many uses of [watchdog timers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) in software (e.g. in the [Parma Polyhedra Library](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl))
Read also about [Worst Case Execution Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_execution_time) (WCET).

So I would say that even in theory it is not possible to rely upon a purely software timer (unless of course that software uses the processor timers, which are hardware circuits). In the previous century (up to 1980s or 1990s) hardware was much more deterministic, and the amount of clock cycles or microsecond needed for each machine instruction was documented (but some instructions, e.g. division, needed a variable amount of time, depending on the actual data!).

Comment: Thanks Basile, so you agree that there is no way to derivate in software the current timestamp from the last hardware timestamp. I accept your answer in.. 5 minutes from now

Comment: In practice, no... Perhaps you could setup things to make it doable, but I don't see the interest... (you'll run one useless loop on your PC sitting in cache, without doing any IO, not even screen display)

Comment: Sorry, I am a father of two and had to take care of them :)

Comment: No problem... I've got 4 kids (the oldest is 36 and the youngest is 17) and 6 grand children...

Comment: BTW, that is a very detailed answer. Some interesting reading ahead :)

Comment: 4 childs, Well done Basile :) I tend to it too. love it :)